# Problems with background video in Xamarin iOS (not Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to insert a video in the background of my app (Login).

I'm using this code in the ViewDidLoad method.

```
MPMoviePlayerController mpPlayer;
mpPlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController (NSUrl.FromFilename ("imagenes/login/video_login.mp4"));
mpPlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;
mpPlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill;
mpPlayer.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;

fondoLogin.Add (mpPlayer.View);
//fondoLogin.AddSubview (mpPlayer.View);

mpPlayer.View.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);

mpPlayer.SourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming;
mpPlayer.SetFullscreen (true, true);
mpPlayer.PrepareToPlay ();
mpPlayer.ShouldAutoplay = true;
videoEndNotificationToken = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver
                                                (AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification, VideoDidFinishPlaying, mpPlayer);
mpPlayer.RepeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One;
mpPlayer.Play ();
```

It doesn't display the video that I put in the resources folder of my project. The video has mp4 format

PS: I'm building on iOS 11 and I want my login to look like Spotify's.

Comment: 1) I would doublecheck that your video is marked with a build action of `BundleResource`, 2) MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated, you should look at using the AVKit framework instead

Comment: Where are you calling this code? setting the views frame should be done in an overriden "LayoutSubviews()" method. Check if the View.Frame.Width and Height are bigger than 0.

Comment: @David Guajardo Make sure your file path is correct. Is `fondoLogin` the subview of `View`?